# What are the odds for any two bodies to collide during the milky way-Andromeda collision?

Tags: galaxy, milky-way, collision

When the two main galaxies of the local group will collide, it is very unlikely for stars to collide with another, but how unlikely is it in the initial collision? And over the whole merging process?